# Specify the entities that compose the activities - CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I need to specify the activities entities on dynamics crm (2015). Specifically, what i need is to limit the option set on Case activity. In this form, i want to let the user add just "Service Activity".
I searched ways to change the data for Case entity (which i understand as the best solution), customize the form (i did not find any form that could be related) and even mark the others entities as non-activity entity (however, the dynamics crm doesn't let me, due to the fact that this check box is disabled on entity customization). 
Is there an way to solve this issue ? (The specific view is in the image attached [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBeQQ.png)).

[image: Form that should be customized]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You can however customize the ribbon of the associated view. Hide the Add New Activity button and create a custom button, e.g. titled Add New Service Activity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know any reason for microsoft to prevent this customization?

Comment: I guess this configuration feature did not get priority enough yet. Also, it is possible to customize the ribbon at this point.